# Removing full title and breadcrumb header container for a specific post type

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions

I have been looking around at how to remove the header container but only for a specific post type with php in the functions.php file of the child theme. For example, portfolio or events. Is this really the best way to go about it or it is better to use Javascript for this?

I suppose there is a way to do it with both languages? but PHP would be ideal.

I have found some articles in stack overflow that shows how to remove it for a specific post ID. It is close to what I need but I need the spot type itself.

Can anyone recommend the best way to hide or remove the full container that holds the title and breadcrumbs for a specific post type via the functions.php file?

The exact post type I am looking to target is either the Portfolio post type or the Event post type. They are not blog post and they are not page post.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, there's no concept of "the" header container in WordPress. What elements are on a page, where they are, and how they got there, is all determined *entirely* by the theme. So, the answer to this:

> Can anyone recommend the best way to hide or remove the full container
>   that holds the title and breadcrumbs for a specific post type via the
>   functions.php file?

Is no. Not really. Not without access to the specific theme in question (keeping in mind that 3rd-party themes and plugins are off-topic here). However, I will walk through some basic steps to go through to find the answer for any given theme.

But first, the simplest option would be to hide it with CSS. This container likely has a class on it, and you could combine that with the `single-event` or `single-portfilio` class to visually hide the header (it will still be in the HTML, just hidden):

```
.single-event .header-container-class {
    display: none;
}
```

Removing it entirely from the code via a template or functions is much more complicated, but here's the steps I'd go through:

**You need to find where this container is being added.**

The first thing to do is look a the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/). Using the Visual Overview, move from the left to the right until you find a file that is in your child theme or parent theme (child theme first). If your post type is named `event`, then you'd be looking for these templates in this order `single-event.php`, `single.php`, `singular.php`, then `index.php`.

The first file you find is the template file WordPress loads for your post type. If `single-event.php` does't exist, then you'll need to move backwards from whichever file you have found to see what other content would also be using that template. Make note of this.

Once you've found the template. Look inside. Compare the HTML to the front-end to see if you can find the container that you want to hide. If you can find this content in the template, then removing it will be fairly straightforward.

**If the file was single-{post type}.php:** Copy the template file to your child theme with the same name. Then in the copy, simply delete the HTML that you don't want. WordPress will load this version of the template from your child theme, and the element won't appear

**If the file was *not* single-{post type}.php:** If the file was not `single-event.php` or `single-portfolio.php` then this means that any changes will also affect regular posts, and possibly pages. In this case, copy the file to the child theme but rename it to `single-{post type}.php` where `post type` is `event` or `portfolio` or whatever the post type is. Then in the copy, delete the HTML that you don't want. Now for this post type WordPress will load the template from your child theme, but the unmodified parent theme's templates for the other post types.

**What to do if the template file you found doesn't have the HTML you want to remove.**

If the template file does not have the HTML that you want to remove, then it is likely being added from another file. Look out for 2 functions being used: `get_header()` and `get_template_part()`.

These functions load in other templates into the template file. Pretty much every template in every theme will use `get_header()`. This loads in the common header that appears on all pages. This might contain the relevant HTML, but first we'll look for `get_template_part()`.

If the template file uses `get_template_part()` then this might be where the header container is coming from. Each use of this function will include a path. `get_template_part( 'partials/header-container' )` means that the template is loading `partials/header-container.php` from the theme, for example.

If your template uses this function, and the file that's referenced contains the HTML that you want to remove, then follow the steps outlined above for copying the `single-` template file, but instead of removing the HTML, just remove the use of `get_template_part()`.

If you still haven't found the HTML, then it's possible that it's being added to every page using `get_header()`. This function simply includes the `header.php` theme file into the template.

So have a look inside `header.php`. If you find the relevant HTML in here, then you'll need a different approach. Copying `header.php` to your child theme and removing the HTML will remove it from every page on the site. Instead you'll need to copy `header.php` to your child theme and add some [Conditional Tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/) checks so that the relevant HTML doesn't appear on certain pages. To exclude a section of the header from the `portfolio` and `event` post types you'd wrap the HTML in these tags:

```
<?php if ( ! is_singular( 'event' ) && ! is_singular( 'portfolio' ) ) : ?>
    <!-- HTML that you don't want to display on Events and Portfolios here. -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

That's about as far as I'll go. If that hasn't helped, then your theme might be doing something unusual, like running everything through hooks. If you've got this far without a solution, I'd suggest contacting the theme author or checking their documentation.